# Abstract CharBuffer and package-private HeapCharBuffer: what's the point?

Tags: java, nio

So, java.nio.CharBuffer is an abstract class, and HeapCharBuffer is package-private. User code can create objects of HeapCharBuffer only through the static methods of the abstract superclass CharBuffer, like this:

```
CharBuffer cb = CharBuffer.allocate(10);
// cb class is now HeapCharBuffer
```

But, why didn't they made CharBuffer a non abstract public class with a set of constructors with the logic of allocate and wrap methods? What's the point in such a concept?

Answer (score 0):

I think this way the author reserves the right to change the concrete implementation of CharBuffer which CharBuffer.allocate returns.

Comment: But user code can use ONLY methods defined in the superclass, thus author can not add new methods, they can only rewrite the methods. So he could do to CharBuffer itself were it a non abstract class